# "There was an error parsing the query" while inserting User

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I've started learning NHibernate. I have the latest version installed and trying to run a very simple application. There's a class `User`:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("User{name='{0}', age={1}}", Name, Age);
    }
}
```

Its mapping is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="cs_nhibernate_test1"
                   namespace="cs_nhibernate_test1">

  <class name="User">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Age" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then, my test program is like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (User).Assembly);
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, true);

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                User user = new User { Name = "John Smith", Age = 25 };
                session.Save(user);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And hibernate.cfg.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=FirstSample.sdf</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
```

The project is .NET 4.0 project, all the required files *seem* to be in output folder.

The error I get is:

> NHibernate: INSERT INTO User (Name, Age, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1,
>   @p2);@p0 = 'John Smith' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 25 [Type: Int32
>   (0)], @p2 = 4b0d4bbf- 7d3c-4bff-908d-ecddfdd8a5cd [Type: Guid (0)]
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There
>   was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line
>   offset = 13,Toke n in error = User ]

Any ideas about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `user` a reserved keyword? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx